# IPython fails to import pandas from Miniconda

Tags: ipython, miniconda

I'm using IPython and pandas to work with Google Bigquery. I installed pandas using 'condas install pandas'. And I believe Miniconda stalled all dependencies. But when I tried to import pandas in IPython notebook, it gave me the following errors:

```
>         
>     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-1-a3826df0a77b> in <module>()
>     ----> 1 import pandas as pd
>           2 
>           3 projectid = "geotab-bigdata-test"
>           4 data_frame = pd.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM RawVin.T20141201', project_id = projectid)
>     
>     C:\Users\fionazhao\Installed\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.pyc
> in <module>()
>          45 
>          46 # let init-time option registration happen
>     ---> 47 import pandas.core.config_init
>          48 
>          49 from pandas.core.api import *
>     
>     C:\Users\fionazhao\Installed\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py
> in <module>()
>          15                                 is_instance_factory, is_one_of_factory,
>          16                                 get_default_val)
>     ---> 17 from pandas.core.format import detect_console_encoding
>          18 
>          19 
>     
>     C:\Users\fionazhao\Installed\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py
> in <module>()
>           7 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
>           8 from pandas.core.common import adjoin, notnull
>     ----> 9 from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index
>          10 from pandas import compat
>          11 from pandas.compat import(StringIO, lzip, range, map, zip, reduce, u,
>     
>     C:\Users\fionazhao\Installed\Continuum\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py
> in <module>()
>          13 import pandas.algos as _algos
>          14 import pandas.index as _index
>     ---> 15 from pandas.lib import Timestamp, Timedelta, is_datetime_array
>          16 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject, FrozenList, FrozenNDArray, IndexOpsMixin, _shared_docs
>          17 from pandas.util.decorators import (Appender, Substitution, cache_readonly,
>     
>     ImportError: cannot import name Timedelta
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solutions myself. When install pandas using Miniconda, we should make sure all python threads have been stopped. Otherwise, it'll messed up the installation and bring such errors.

I just stopped all python threads, re-install pandas by 'conda install -f pandas', and the errors gone